# Customise wordpress theme search.php to include product image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, search

I want my search results to show an image of the product. Currently the search results only show a text link. My wordpress theme is Intuition Pro and the website is https://heritagecountrypottery.com. I am also using the Ivory search wordpress plugin

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main" class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <section id="content" class="content">
            <?php do_action('cpotheme_before_content'); ?>
            <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
            <article class="search-result" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">            
                <h4 class="search-title heading">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h4>
                <div class="search-byline">
                    <?php the_permalink(); ?>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php cpotheme_numbered_pagination(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php do_action('cpotheme_after_content'); ?>
        </section>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have searched online for a solution but have not found one that works with my theme

Answer (score 0):

You can get the post thumbnail like this

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
    <div class="search-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can add it before the `heading`, but you need to figure out the CSS rules you have to apply to make it looks good.

Comment: Dear Tasos, Thanks again that worked beautifully. Could you possibly show me how to make the image a link as well? Currently only the text below image is linked to the relevant page. Regards Garry

Comment: You can wrap the image with an `<a>` and use the `the_permalink()` to get the url of the product. Don't forget, if you are satisfied with the answer to upvote and mark the answer as correct to help future visitors

Comment: Fantastic - thanks again Tasos. Apologies for being a fool but where is this "upvote and mark as correct"?